# burnt Switches connected directly to the internet

Tags: switch, mac-address, packetloss

We got a setup with a switch between the cable modem/bridge and the two router ports.

We burn this switch every 6 months, and it has to be replaced.
Symptoms are heavy packet loss or in general very slow connection. This is the third device now.

I'm getting suspicous now, as every other component inside the LAN keeps working with no problem for years, even with same manufacturers.

Q: **Does a switch that is connected to the inet directly in general have really much to do**, ie flushing the MAC table over and over again? Which would mean its memory is under much heavier stress than in any other place in the LAN?

The switch has a consumer sized MAC table size, we've got a total of about 80 machines behind the router every day.

Thanks for your idea-

Ps: Would this be one of the rare occasions to use a hub?

Edit:

- The ports on the router are two WAN ports
- yes the temperature is a bit raised, about 25 deg C. But all the other (managed, bigger) switches are in the same room. no issues.
- Burn: I mean it is broken. I narrowed it down by replacing the router and any other device that comes in question. I finally did extensive ping tests to servers like 8.8.8.8 and found out it's caused by the switch, at the moment it happens (it doesn't always). I checked with the net provider for network issues, got my "modem" tested, had my line monitored for weeks... and all the replacements of this switch fixed it at once, permanently (for months)
- thanks for the "should have little to do" part. I think it must be true, given there are no other devices connected.

I guess the **solution**:
I meanwhile found out from two other network administrators that they had the same problems, with exact this model. (It was the Netgear Prosafe Series, including the Business branch of that line) They "preach" Cisco ever since, they checked their case without doubt. And I'm going to go just there, starting tomorrow.

Finally. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "two router ports"?

Comment: Looks more like this swith is placed on a place with high temperatures, low ventilation ... Indeed a swith connected to internet should be less busy than one working on a LAN.

Comment: `We burn this switch every 6 months` - What does that mean, exactly? How are you measuring and monitoring this alleged packet loss? How are you diagnosing the problem when it occurs? How did you narrow the problem down to the switch?